# Is it possible to set a background image inside JTextArea (including JScrollPane) not all the frame window?

Tags: java, swing

I want to set background in JTextArea (having transparency), but I don't have any idea. Maybe it's not very important, but I just want have characteristically program. Please help.

This part of code, I create JTextArea.

```
notatnik_k = new JTextArea();
JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(notatnik_k);
scrollPane2.setBounds(20,30, 263,200);
notatnik_k.setEditable(false);  
add(scrollPane2);
```

This photo showing my problem:

[image: Photo inside JTextArea including transparency]

Is there a simply way, to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to extend your JTextArea class and create a `setBackground(Image image)` method. This method would set a field to the image you want to use and then invoke the the repaint method (`this.repaint()`).

You should then override the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method to paint the component with the image you set using `setBackground(Image image)`.

Answer (score 0):

I found here on the site this sample of code, and I did a little change but I have one error and don't know why it's incorrect? It's shows error: "The method setBackgroundImage(Image) is undefined for the type JTextArea"

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class BackgroundDemo {

    public JTextArea notatnik;

    private static void createAndShowUI() {

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        }

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("BackgroundDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();

        final JTextArea notatnik = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(notatnik);
        scrollPane1.setBounds(20,270, 380,110);


       JButton loadButton = new JButton("Set background");
        buttonsPanel.add(loadButton);

        loadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.home"));
                int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(frame);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    try {
                        Image image = ImageIO.read(fc.getSelectedFile());
                        if (image != null)
                            notatnik.setBackgroundImage(image);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        content.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.add(scrollPane1);
        frame.add(content);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 500));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);      
    }

    static class MyTextArea extends JTextArea {
        private Image backgroundImage;

        public MyTextArea() {
            super();
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        public void setBackgroundImage(Image image) {
            this.backgroundImage = image;
            this.repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(getBackground());
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            if (backgroundImage != null) {
                g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, this);
            }
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason you're getting an error is because you've declared `notatnik` as a `JTextArea`, this classes doesn't have a method called `setBackgroundImage`...neither did you create an instance of `MyTextArea`, so it will never work anyway..

Comment: I used the code from the subject of the first response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992831/inserting-an-image-under-a-jtextarea , is it possible to set the transparency of the image in the background?

Comment: :( I'dont have any idea, how to set image inside JTextArea, not on all the screen. I saw a lot of examples, but all of them are about how to set background on the all screen.

Comment: You can make the image transparent using a AlphaComposite, but that's another question ;)

Comment: AlphaComposite is external library?

Comment: Nope, it's part of the 2D Graphics API

Comment: Ok, maybe You can give me a tips, what should I looking for to find answer for my problem? More keywords?