# Drawing text from keyboard input on a canvas

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I want to make a paint program.
When the user clicks the text button, then the user click the canvas the user can input the text they want in the clicked location.

What can I use to make that happen?

When i use `drawstring`, I can put the pre-defined text and user click location

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 40);
g2.setFont(font);
g2.drawString("text", x, y);
```

How can I change `"text"` to what the user inputs from keyboard?

My MainPanel Code (For View Mostly)

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, ChangeListener {
private JButton button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10, button11, button12, activeButton;
private ButtonGroup buttonGroup;
private DrawPanel drawPanel;
private boolean insertedDrawPanel;
private JSlider slider;
private JTextField valueField;
private int jSliderMin, jSliderMax, jSliderInit;

private Toolkit toolkit;
private Image cursorImage;
private Point cursorHotSpot;
private Cursor fillCursor, penCursor, eraserCursor, lineCursor, rectCursor, ovalCursor, triangleCursor, starCursor;
private Color color1, color2;

public MainPanel()
{
    try {
        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel( javax.swing.UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280, 720));
    initiateComponent();
    buildLayout();
    registerListener();
    checkDrawPanel();
}

public JPanel getDrawPanel() {
    return drawPanel;
}

public void initiateComponent()
{
    int width=54;
    int height=48;

    jSliderMin=1;
    jSliderMax=100;
    jSliderInit=1;

    insertedDrawPanel=false;

    BufferedImage buttonIcon;

    activeButton= new JButton();

    button1 = new JButton();
    button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    button1.setName("");
    button2 = new JButton();
    button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    button2.setName("");
    button3 = new JButton();
    button3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    button4 = new JButton("");
    button4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    button5 = new JButton("");
    button5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    button6 = new JButton("");
    button6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    button7 = new JButton("1");
    button7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    button8 = new JButton("2");
    button8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    button9 = new JButton("");
    button9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    button10 = new JButton("");
    button10.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    button11 = new JButton("");
    button11.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    button12 = new JButton("");
    button12.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));


public void buildLayout()
{
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    String colSizes = "20px, 54px, 10px, 54px, 20px";
    String rowSizes = "20px, 48px, 20px, 48px, 20px, 48px, 20px, 48px, 20px, 200px, 48px, 48px, 20px, 48px";
    FormLayout layout = new FormLayout(colSizes, rowSizes);
    buttonPanel.setLayout(layout);
    CellConstraints cc = new CellConstraints();
    buttonPanel.add(button1, cc.xy(2, 2));
    buttonPanel.add(button2, cc.xy(4, 2));
    buttonPanel.add(button3, cc.xy(2, 4));
    buttonPanel.add(button4, cc.xy(4, 4));
    buttonPanel.add(button5, cc.xy(2, 6));
    buttonPanel.add(button6, cc.xy(4, 6));
    buttonPanel.add(button7, cc.xy(2, 8));
    buttonPanel.add(button8, cc.xy(4, 8));
    buttonPanel.add(slider,  cc.xywh(2, 10, 3, 1));
    buttonPanel.add(valueField, cc.xyw(2, 11, 3));
    buttonPanel.add(button9, cc.xy(2, 12));
    buttonPanel.add(button10, cc.xy(4, 12));
    buttonPanel.add(button11, cc.xy(2, 14));
    buttonPanel.add(button12, cc.xy(4, 14));

    this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
}

public void registerListener()
{
    button1.addActionListener(this);
    button2.addActionListener(this);
    button3.addActionListener(this);
    button4.addActionListener(this);
    button5.addActionListener(this);
    button6.addActionListener(this);
    button7.addActionListener(this);
    button8.addActionListener(this);
    button9.addActionListener(this);
    button10.addActionListener(this);
    button11.addActionListener(this);
    button12.addActionListener(this);
    slider.addChangeListener(this);
}

public void addDrawPanel(DrawPanel panel)
{
    drawPanel=panel;
    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    String colSizes = "20px, pref,20px";
    String rowSizes = "20px, pref,20px";
    FormLayout layout = new FormLayout(colSizes, rowSizes);
    centerPanel.setLayout(layout);
    CellConstraints cc = new CellConstraints();
    centerPanel.add(drawPanel, cc.xy(2, 2));

    this.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    insertedDrawPanel=true;
    checkDrawPanel();
}

public void addOpenedImage(Image img)
{
    drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
    drawPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(img.getWidth(null),img.getHeight(null)));
    drawPanel.setBgImg(img);
    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    String colSizes = "20px, pref,20px";
    String rowSizes = "20px, pref,20px";
    FormLayout layout = new FormLayout(colSizes, rowSizes);
    centerPanel.setLayout(layout);
    CellConstraints cc = new CellConstraints();
    centerPanel.add(drawPanel, cc.xy(2, 2));

    this.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    insertedDrawPanel=true;
    checkDrawPanel();
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if(ae.getSource().equals(button1))
    {
        activeButton=button1;
        this.setCursor(penCursor);

        resetButtonChanges();
        drawPanel.setPenActive(true);
    }

    if(ae.getSource().equals(button2))
    {
        activeButton=button2;
        this.setCursor(lineCursor);

        resetButtonChanges();
        drawPanel.setLineActive(true);
    }

    if(ae.getSource().equals(button3))
    {
        activeButton=button3;
        this.setCursor(eraserCursor);

        resetButtonChanges();
        drawPanel.setEraserActive(true);
    }

    if(ae.getSource().equals(button4))
    {
        activeButton=button4;

        resetButtonChanges();
        drawPanel.setTextActive(true);
    }

    if(ae.getSource().equals(button7))
    {
        activeButton= button7;

        resetButtonChanges();

        color1 = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Pick your Background Color", color1);


        if(color1!=null)
        {
            drawPanel.setBackground(color1);
        }

    }

    if(ae.getSource().equals(button8))
    {
        activeButton= button8;

        resetButtonChanges();

        color2 = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Pick your Stroke / Shape Color", color2);

        if(color2!=null)
        {
            drawPanel.setStrokecolor(color2);
        }

    }

    if(ae.getSource().equals(button9))
    {
        activeButton=button9;
        this.setCursor(rectCursor);

        resetButtonChanges();
        drawPanel.setRectActive(true);
    }

    if(ae.getSource().equals(button10))
    {
        activeButton=button10;
        this.setCursor(ovalCursor);

        resetButtonChanges();
        drawPanel.setOvalActive(true);
    }

    if(ae.getSource().equals(button11))
    {
        activeButton=button11;
        this.setCursor(triangleCursor);

        resetButtonChanges();
        drawPanel.setTriangleActive(true);
    }

    if(ae.getSource().equals(button12))
    {
        activeButton=button12;
        this.setCursor(starCursor);

        resetButtonChanges();
        drawPanel.setStarActive(true);
    }

}

public void resetButtonChanges()
{
    if(activeButton!=button1)
    {
        drawPanel.setPenActive(false);
    }
    if(activeButton!=button2)
    {
        drawPanel.setLineActive(false);
    }
    if(activeButton!=button3)
    {
        drawPanel.setEraserActive(false);
    }
    if(activeButton!=button4)
    {
        drawPanel.setTextActive(false);
    }
    if(activeButton!=button9)
    {
        drawPanel.setRectActive(false);
    }
    if(activeButton!=button10)
    {
        drawPanel.setOvalActive(false);
    }
    if(activeButton!=button11)
    {
        drawPanel.setTriangleActive(false);
    }
    if(activeButton!=button12)
    {
        drawPanel.setStarActive(false);
    }
}

public void checkDrawPanel()
{
    if(insertedDrawPanel==false)
    {
        button1.setEnabled(false);
        button2.setEnabled(false);
        button3.setEnabled(false);
        button4.setEnabled(false);
        button5.setEnabled(false);
        button6.setEnabled(false);
        button7.setEnabled(false);
        button8.setEnabled(false);
        button9.setEnabled(false);
        button10.setEnabled(false);
        button11.setEnabled(false);
        button12.setEnabled(false);
        slider.setEnabled(false);
    }

    else
    {
        button1.setEnabled(true);
        button2.setEnabled(true);
        button3.setEnabled(true);
        button4.setEnabled(true);
        button5.setEnabled(true);
        button6.setEnabled(true);
        button7.setEnabled(true);
        button8.setEnabled(true);
        button9.setEnabled(true);
        button10.setEnabled(true);
        button11.setEnabled(true);
        button12.setEnabled(true);
        slider.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
     if(ce.getSource().equals(slider))
     {
        drawPanel.setStrokevalue(slider.getValue());
        valueField.setText(String.valueOf(slider.getValue()));
     }

     if(ce.getSource().equals(button7))
     {
         button7.setBackground(color1);
         button7.setForeground(color2);
     }

     if(ce.getSource().equals(button8))
     {
         button8.setBackground(color2);
         button8.setForeground(color1);
     }
}
```

}

My DrawPanel Code

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, FocusListener, DocumentListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

```
private boolean penActive ,eraserActive, lineActive, rectActive, ovalActive, triangleActive, starActive, textActive, isDrag, isReleased;
private int x, y , xDrag, yDrag, xRelease, yRelease, strokevalue;
private Color strokecolor ,dragColor;
private Vector<int[]> allShapes;
private int[] dragShape;
private Vector<Color> shapeColor;
private Vector<String> type;
private String dragType;
private JTextField text;

private Image bgImg;

public boolean isPenActive() {
    return penActive;
}

public void setPenActive(boolean penActive) {
    this.penActive = penActive;
}

public boolean isEraserActive() {
    return eraserActive;
}

public void setEraserActive(boolean eraserActive) {
    this.eraserActive = eraserActive;
}

public boolean isTriangleActive() {
    return triangleActive;
}

public void setTriangleActive(boolean triangleActive) {
    this.triangleActive = triangleActive;
}

public boolean isLineActive() {
    return lineActive;
}

public void setLineActive(boolean lineActive) {
    this.lineActive = lineActive;
}

public int getStrokevalue() {
    return strokevalue;
}

public void setStrokevalue(int strokevalue) {
    this.strokevalue = strokevalue;
}

public Color getStrokecolor() {
    return strokecolor;
}

public void setStrokecolor(Color strokecolor) {
    this.strokecolor = strokecolor;
}

public boolean isRectActive() {
    return rectActive;
}

public void setRectActive(boolean rectActive) {
    this.rectActive = rectActive;
}

public boolean isOvalActive() {
    return ovalActive;
}

public void setOvalActive(boolean ovalActive) {
    this.ovalActive = ovalActive;
}

public boolean isStarActive() {
    return starActive;
}

public void setStarActive(boolean starActive) {
    this.starActive = starActive;
}

public boolean isTextActive() {
    return textActive;
}

public void setTextActive(boolean textActive) {
    this.textActive = textActive;
}

public Image getBgImg() {
    return bgImg;
}

public void setBgImg(Image bgImg) {
    this.bgImg = bgImg;
}




public DrawPanel()
{
    setFocusable(true);
    setBackground(Color.white);
    initiateComponents();
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    addMouseListener(this);
}

public void initiateComponents()
{
    allShapes=new Vector<int[]>();
    shapeColor=new Vector<Color>();
    type=new Vector<String>();

    eraserActive = false;
    penActive = false;
    lineActive = false;
    rectActive = false;
    ovalActive = false;
    triangleActive = false;
    starActive = false;
    strokevalue=1;
    strokecolor=Color.BLACK;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {

    if (me.getClickCount() == 2)
        text.setEditable( true );


}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) { 
    x = me.getX(); 
    y = me.getY();   

    if(me.getClickCount() == 1)
    {
        this.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
    if(me.getClickCount() == 2)
    {
        System.out.println("asd");
        text.setLocation(me.getPoint());
        this.add(text);
        text.requestFocusInWindow();
        text.selectAll();
        repaint();
    }


}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
    isDrag=false;
    isReleased=true;
    xRelease=me.getX();
    yRelease=me.getY();
    repaint();

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {

}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
    isDrag=true;
    isReleased=false;
    xDrag=me.getX();
    yDrag=me.getY();

    repaint();



}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    if(penActive==true)
    {

        int[]coordinates=new int[5];

        if(isDrag)
        {
            coordinates[0]=x;
            coordinates[1]=y;
            coordinates[2]=xDrag;
            coordinates[3]=yDrag;
            coordinates[4]=strokevalue;

            allShapes.add(coordinates);

            shapeColor.add(strokecolor);
            type.add("Pen");

            x=xDrag;
            y=yDrag;
        }

    }

    else if(eraserActive==true)
    {
        int[]coordinates=new int[5]; 

        if(isDrag)
        {
            coordinates[0]=x;
            coordinates[1]=y;
            coordinates[2]=xDrag;
            coordinates[3]=yDrag;
            coordinates[4]=strokevalue;
            allShapes.add(coordinates);

            shapeColor.add(this.getBackground());
            type.add("Eraser");

            x=xDrag;
            y=yDrag;
        }
    }

    else if(lineActive==true)
    {
        int[]coordinates=new int[5]; 

        if(isDrag)
        {
            dragShape=new int[5];
            dragShape[0]=x;
            dragShape[1]=y;
            dragShape[2]=xDrag;
            dragShape[3]=yDrag;
            dragShape[4]=strokevalue;

            dragColor=strokecolor;

            dragType="Line";
        }

        if(isReleased)
        {
            dragShape=null;
            coordinates[0]=x;
            coordinates[1]=y;
            coordinates[2]=xDrag;
            coordinates[3]=yDrag;
            coordinates[4]=strokevalue;
            allShapes.add(coordinates);

            shapeColor.add(strokecolor);
            type.add("Line");
        }
    }

    else if(textActive==true)
    {
        int[]coordinates=new int[3]; 

        if(isReleased)
        {
            dragShape=null;
            coordinates[0]=x;
            coordinates[1]=y;
            coordinates[2]=strokevalue;
            allShapes.add(coordinates);

            shapeColor.add(strokecolor);
            type.add("Text");
        }
    }

    else if(triangleActive==true)
    {
        int[]coordinates=new int[4];

        if(isDrag)
        {
            dragShape=new int[4];
            dragShape[0]=x;
            dragShape[1]=y;
            dragShape[2]=-y+yDrag;
            dragShape[3]=strokevalue;

            dragColor=strokecolor;

            dragType="Triangle";
        }

        if(isReleased)
        {
            dragShape=null;
            coordinates[0]=x;
            coordinates[1]=y;
            coordinates[2]=-y+yDrag;
            coordinates[3]=strokevalue;

            allShapes.add(coordinates);

            shapeColor.add(strokecolor);
            type.add("Triangle");
        }
    }

    else if(starActive==true)
    {
        int[]coordinates=new int[4];

        if(isDrag)
        {
            dragShape=new int[4];
            dragShape[0]=x;
            dragShape[1]=y;
            dragShape[2]=-y+yDrag;
            dragShape[3]=strokevalue;

            dragColor=strokecolor;

            dragType="Star";
        }

        if(isReleased)
        {
            dragShape=null;
            coordinates[0]=x;
            coordinates[1]=y;
            coordinates[2]=-y+yDrag;
            coordinates[3]=strokevalue;

            allShapes.add(coordinates);

            shapeColor.add(strokecolor);
            type.add("Star");
        }
    }

    else if(rectActive==true)
    {
        int[]coordinates=new int[5];

        if(isDrag)
        {
            dragShape=new int[5];
            dragShape[0]=x;
            dragShape[1]=y;
            dragShape[2]=xDrag;
            dragShape[3]=yDrag;
            dragShape[4]= strokevalue;

            dragColor=strokecolor;

            dragType="Rectangle";

        }

        if(isReleased)
        {
            dragShape=null;
            coordinates[0]=x;
            coordinates[1]=y;
            coordinates[2]=xDrag;
            coordinates[3]=yDrag;
            coordinates[4]=strokevalue;

            allShapes.add(coordinates);

            shapeColor.add(strokecolor);
            type.add("Rectangle");
        }
    }

    else if(ovalActive==true)
    {
        int[]coordinates=new int[4];

        if(isDrag)
        {
            dragShape=new int[4];
            dragShape[0]=x;
            dragShape[1]=y;
            dragShape[2]=-y+yDrag;
            dragShape[3]=strokevalue;

            dragColor=strokecolor;

            dragType="Oval";
        }

        if(isReleased)
        {
            dragShape=null;
            coordinates[0]=x;
            coordinates[1]=y;
            coordinates[2]=-y+yDrag;
            coordinates[3]=strokevalue;

            allShapes.add(coordinates);

            shapeColor.add(strokecolor);
            type.add("Oval");
        }
    }

    if(bgImg!=null)
    {
        g2.drawImage(bgImg, 0, 0, null);
    }


    for(int a=0;a<allShapes.size();a++)
    {
        if(type.get(a).equals("Pen")||type.get(a).equals("Eraser")||type.get(a).equals("Line"))
        {

            int[]coordinates=allShapes.get(a);
            Color color=shapeColor.get(a);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(coordinates[4]));     
            g2.setPaint(color);
            g2.drawLine(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], coordinates[2], coordinates[3]);
        }

        else if(type.get(a).equals("Text"))
        {
            text = new JTextField("asd");
            Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 40);


            g2.setFont(font);

        }

        else if(type.get(a).equals("Triangle"))
        {
            int[]coordinates=allShapes.get(a);
            Point2D b= new Point2D.Double(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]);

            Triangle triangle = new Triangle(b,coordinates[2]);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(coordinates[3]));
            g2.setPaint(dragColor);
            g2.draw(triangle);
        }

        else if(type.get(a).equals("Star"))
        {
            int[]coordinates=allShapes.get(a);
            Point2D b= new Point2D.Double(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]);

            Star star = new Star(b,coordinates[2], coordinates[2]);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(coordinates[3]));
            g2.setPaint(dragColor);
            g2.draw(star);
        }

        else if(type.get(a).equals("Rectangle"))
        {
            int[]coordinates=allShapes.get(a);

            Point2D b=new Point2D.Double(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]);
            Point2D c=new Point2D.Double(coordinates[2], coordinates[3]);

            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(b,c);

            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(coordinates[4]));
            g2.setPaint(dragColor);
            g2.draw(rectangle);
        }

        else if(type.get(a).equals("Oval"))
        {
            int[]coordinates=allShapes.get(a);
            Point2D b= new Point2D.Double(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]);

            Circle oval = new Circle(b,coordinates[0], coordinates[1], coordinates[2]);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(coordinates[3]));
            g2.setPaint(dragColor);
            g2.draw(oval);
        }

    }

    if(dragShape!=null)
    {
        if(dragType.equals("Line"))
        {
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(dragShape[4]));
            g2.setPaint(dragColor);
            g2.drawLine(dragShape[0], dragShape[1], dragShape[2], dragShape[3]);
        }

        else if(dragType.equals("Triangle"))
        {
            Point2D a= new Point2D.Double(dragShape[0], dragShape[1]);

            Triangle triangle = new Triangle(a,dragShape[2]);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(dragShape[3]));
            g2.setPaint(dragColor);
            g2.draw(triangle);
        }

        else if(dragType.equals("Star"))
        {
            Point2D a= new Point2D.Double(dragShape[0], dragShape[1]);

            Star star = new Star(a,dragShape[2],dragShape[2]);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(dragShape[3]));
            g2.setPaint(dragColor);
            g2.draw(star);
        }

        else if(dragType.equals("Rectangle")){

            Point2D b=new Point2D.Double(dragShape[0], dragShape[1]);
            Point2D c=new Point2D.Double(dragShape[2], dragShape[3]);

            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(b,c);

            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(dragShape[4]));
            g2.setPaint(dragColor);
            g2.draw(rectangle);
        }

        else if(dragType.equals("Oval"))
        {
            Point2D a= new Point2D.Double(dragShape[0], dragShape[1]);

            Circle oval = new Circle(a,dragShape[0],dragShape[1], dragShape[2]);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(dragShape[3]));
            g2.setPaint(dragColor);
            g2.draw(oval);
        }

    }


}

@Override
public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    text.setEditable(false);
}

@Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    text.setSize(getPreferredSize());
}

@Override
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    text.setSize(getPreferredSize());
}

@Override
public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    text.setEditable(false);
}
```

}

Comment: Conceptually, you could do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737266/custom-java-swing-textcomponent-from-scratch/12737418#12737418).  This basically adds a `JTextArea` to the place the user clicks, allowing them to type in what ever they want.  What you would need to do is, at some point when they "commit" the text is store the resulting `String` and paint it using `Graphics2D` ... or just keep the `JTextArea` :P

Comment: This is another [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560065/how-to-write-text-over-image-inside-rectangular-region-displayed-in-jpanel/13561675#13561675) of the same idea

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that uses a JTextField to enter text at the location.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class InvisibleTextField extends JTextField
    implements ActionListener, FocusListener, MouseListener, DocumentListener
{
    public InvisibleTextField()
    {
        setOpaque( false );
        setColumns( 1 );
//      setBorder( null );
        setSize( getPreferredSize() );
        setColumns( 0 );
        addActionListener( this );
        addFocusListener( this );
        addMouseListener( this );
        getDocument().addDocumentListener( this );
    }

//  Implement ActionListener

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        setEditable( false );
    }

//  Implement FocusListener

    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
    {
        setEditable( false );
    }

    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {}

//  Implement MouseListener

    public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e )
    {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2)
            setEditable( true );
    }

    public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent e ) {}

    public void mouseExited( MouseEvent e ) {}

    public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e ) {}

    public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent e ) {}

//  Implement DocumentListener

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        updateSize();
    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        updateSize();
    }

    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}

    private void updateSize()
    {
        setSize( getPreferredSize() );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setFocusable( true );
        panel.setLayout( null );
        panel.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
            {
                JPanel panel = (JPanel)e.getSource();

                if (e.getClickCount() == 1)
                {
                    panel.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
                if (e.getClickCount() == 2)
                {
                    InvisibleTextField tf = new InvisibleTextField();
                    tf.setLocation(e.getPoint());
                    panel.add( tf );
                    tf.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.add(new JLabel("Double Click to Add Text"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(650, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

You can edit the text at any time by double clicking on the text.

Comment: How can i Implement this on my program ? 

Can i just copy the method to a new class
and my drawPanel have a button, and if that button is Click, it triggers that method ?

Everytime i do that, it loops at public InvisibleTextField()

Comment: @HendraSetiawan, you just add the MouseListener code to your panel. You don't use a button. The reason you use a MouseListener is so you can get the point where the mouse was clicked so you know where to add the text field.

Comment: Emm , i mean the button is clicked, and then the button activates the function, can you take a look at my full code? i'll edit my post right now to post the full code.

if u have the time please have a look :)